# Move Files older then 31 days to another drive

Tags: powershell, time, file, get, move

```
Function Move {
  #Moves all files older than 31 days old from the Source folder to the Target 
  Get-Childitem -Path "E:\source" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-31)} |
  ForEach {
    Move-Item $_.FullName -destination "F:\target" -force -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
  }
}
```

in the source directory are files that are older than 2-3 years, but when i run the script nothing moves to the target directory ?! whats wrong ?

Comment: If you take out the ErrorAction does it produce any errors?

Comment: Are your files in `E:\source` exactly or in its subdirectories? In the latter case use `Get-Childitem -Recurse`

Comment: FYI, that will not move files in sub directories.

Comment: I suggest  using in a script the robocopy command with /mov and /minage: flags.

Answer (score 33):

I don't know if this makes much of a difference, but rather than $. it needs to be $_.

I tried this script and it works fine for me:

```
get-childitem -Path "E:\source" |
    where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-31)} | 
    move-item -destination "F:\target"
```

Notice you don't need a foreach loop because the objects will be "piped" into the move-item command

Comment: get-currentitem you mean Get-Childitem ?

Comment: why does it not work for me...very strange. i thought about the foreach to avoid problems, cause we have 20k+ files in some directorys....

Comment: @JPBlanc: Thanks very much, yes I do mean get-childitem. I'm used to writing gci. Have updated my post

Comment: @Maurizio Schmidt: If you have files in subfolders this won't do it. You'll have to use the -Recurse flag on get-childitem, and additionally you'll have to work out how to move to the right folder on the destinations

Comment: @ Matthew: Now it works perfectly, thx. i thought the foreach etc is necessary to avoid memory consumption problems caused by the fact that within some directorys we´ve more then 30.000 files.

Comment: @Maurizio Schmidt: I don't know what the limits will be for memory, but if you've got too many files then I think you'll encounter the problem on the get-childitem method (as that will load them all up to begin with).

Answer (score 4):

Also be aware of hidden files, try adding `-Force` to `Get-ChildItem`