# automatically move older files to specific repositories with git-annex (assistant)?

Tags: linux, git, archive, git-annex

I'm looking for an archiving solution that allows both local and cloud backup.  [git-annex assistant](https://downloads.kitenet.net/videos/git-annex/git-annex-assistant-intro.ogv) looks like the best way to do this for linux.

However, I would like to tag older files (not accessed in more than 6 months) to go to amazon glacier, but I can't figure out how to do this with git-annex assistant.  Is this possible with git-annex (assistant)?  I'm not afraid of the command line / scripts if it needs some sort of hook.  If this is not possible with git-annex or the assistant does anyone know of other tools (besides rolling your own all the way from rsync) that can accomplish what I am trying to do?

There is a question about moving files older than a certain date for [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912051/move-files-older-then-31-days-to-another-drive) (and surely a similar `find | xargs` solution too).  However, I am looking for an automated archiving solution in linux.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job. git is a revision management tool, not a backup/archival utility.

Comment: @duskwuff, Have you seen/used git-annex assistant?